# Positioning in TikZ of a single node

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am trying since a while to create a `tikzpicture` with a single centered node. But, all I found about positioning concerns relative positioning and doesnt work on a single node.

For example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0, 6) (A)  {$e$};
\path (A) edge [loop above]             node {$\alpha$} (A)
          edge [loop left]              node {$\beta$} (A)
          edge [loop right]             node {$\gamma$} (A)
          edge [loop below]             node {$\delta$} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

does still place the node on the left side. Has anyone an idea how this could work? ;)

Comment: Just add `\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}\end{center}` as one of many other options. This is if I understood what your problem is correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried with "\centering" but I couldnt handle it and it messed with my definitions. With \begin{center}... it works very well.

Comment: \centering ends when the group ends.  {\centering ...} or \bgroup\centering ... \egroup.  Every environment is a group.

Comment: If you use `figure`, use `\centering`. If not, use `\center`.

Comment: off-topic: in your image `\node[draw] at (0, 6) (A)  {$e$};`  gives the same result as use `\node[draw] at (0, 0) (A)  {$e$};` or `\node[draw] (A)  {$e$};`

Answer (score 1):

with image content you can't (explicit) determine its position in the text (exception is absolute position regarding to page anchors with `remember picture` and `overlay` options/macros). for example, in your *mwe* you for positioning of node use:

```
\node[draw] at (0, 6) (A) {$e$};
```

but this gives the same position of your picture as with use

```
\node[draw] at (0, 0) (A) {$e$};
```

or

```
\node[draw] (A) {$e$};
```

influence on image position has content image only in cases, when the picture is wider than text, then you can center it only with locally creasing text width.

for centering, as are mentioned in comments, you can use (special) environments:

- when you not allow floating of your image:

```
\begin{center}
< your image >
\end{center}
```

- when you allow floating (usual use), than you should use floating environment `figure`:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering % <--- for center image in environment
< your image >
\end{figure}
```

where `[htb]` are options for positioning of figure in text (`htb`: here or top or bottom)

examples of your image positioning:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0, 6) (A)  {$e$};
\path (A) edge [loop above]             node {$\alpha$} (A)
          edge [loop left]              node {$\beta$} (A)
          edge [loop right]             node {$\gamma$} (A)
          edge [loop below]             node {$\delta$} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] at (0, 0) (A)  {$e$};
\path (A) edge [loop above]             node {$\alpha$} (A)
          edge [loop left]              node {$\beta$} (A)
          edge [loop right]             node {$\gamma$} (A)
          edge [loop below]             node {$\delta$} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
or in case when you like to have caption describing figure
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (A)  {$e$};
\path (A) edge [loop above]             node {$\alpha$} (A)
          edge [loop left]              node {$\beta$} (A)
          edge [loop right]             node {$\gamma$} (A)
          edge [loop below]             node {$\delta$} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{my very nice picture}
    \label{fig:node-loops}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[11]
    \end{document}
```

[image]